# Play Framework 2.1 Scala - form binding for date

Tags: forms, scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I want to create a form binding in Play Framework 2.1, for a form that has date/time fields. Is there any standard verifier for date/time input? I understand that the page form should also send the date/time in a particular format. Does anyone know of any prefab solution for that? Or can describe how to implement one by myself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Play 2.1 has [built-in support](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaFormHelpers) for Twitter Bootstrap; if you take that route then [Bootstrap Date Picker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker) is a good call for client-side (i.e. ensuring date is sent as `yyyy-mm-dd` or other valid date format).

With the client taken care of, server-side Play 2.1 supports [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), so you can bind the post'd form date like so:

```
object FooForm {
  import play.api.data.{Form, Forms}, Forms._
  val mapper = mapping(
    'fooDate-> jodaDate("yyyy-MM-dd")
  )(Foo.apply)(Foo.unapply)
  val form = Form( mapper )
}
```

Comment: Any way to have the Java equivalent?

Comment: not sure about the java form API, similar should be possible, particularly in Play 2.3, they've been putting a lot of work into the Java side of the framework.

Comment: For me not work, my code manual import JodaTime
`code` import org.joda.time.DateTime
case class CompanyFormInput(company_name: String, date_created: DateTime)

Answer (score 1):

Like @virtualeyes said, from the client side, [DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) will generate the correct data format (dd/MM/yyyy by default).

However, Play Framework then needs to unmarshall the Date format correctly using  `bindFronRequest` (client -> server).

Also Play needs to generate the correct Date string representation when generating the Form, which will be sent to the view (controller -> view). In **java** this can be done providing a [DataBinder](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaForms).

An example of this can be found in that [**issue opened on GitHub**](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3097#issuecomment-47441276)